# Autocomplete Keybindings in TextMate 2 - LaTeX Bundle

Tags: editors, mactex, textmate

Recently began learning LaTeX and I am using TextMate 2 with the LaTeX bundle (and Tex Live distribution) to create my files.

I cannot get the autocomplete keybinding to work within the document (which is assigned to escape or option-escape) and I have to manually click through the toolbars to access the auto-complete, which is less than optimal.

I'm hoping anyone who works in the editor can help with my question.

Am I missing something very obvious? I am new to both LaTeX and TextMate 2.

Comment: Works fine here. Can you please try the following. 1. Create a  new `tex`-file 2. Enter a partial command such as `\tab` 3. Press `^⌘T` 4. Search for “Command Completion” 5. Select the command 6. Press Enter. Does this work?

Comment: Nothing comes up with CTRL+CMD+T with any partial command. I've been testing it with \raisebox but the only thing that works is selecting it in the dropdown menu at the bottom of the editor.

Comment: If you say nothing comes up when you press `^⌘T`, do you mean that (1) no “Select Bundle Item” window pop up appears after you press the shortcut, (2) the list shown in the “Select Bundle Item” window is empty or (3) the command did not work after you selected it? Does the normal command completion `⎋` work in other grammars such as “Plain Text”? You can test this using the following steps: 1. Create a new plain text file 2. Enter text such as `bla blubb bl` 3. Make sure your caret is located right after `bl` 4. Press `⎋` repeatedly . TextMate should then toggle between `bla` and `blubb`.